# Adding a Tabhost to an android project

Tags: java, android, android-studio, fragment-tab-host

I'm following the sample provided in this link to create a TabHost. But I got "Fatal Exception" error. --> http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/TabActivity.html

activity_main.xml

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="polimi.aap.yas.personalhealthrecord.MainActivity">


    <android.support.v4.app.FragmentTabHost
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@android:id/tabhost"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <LinearLayout
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">

            <TabWidget
                android:id="@android:id/tabs"
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="0"/>

            <FrameLayout
                android:id="@android:id/tabcontent"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                android:layout_weight="0"/>

            <FrameLayout
                android:id="@+id/realtabcontent"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"/>

        </LinearLayout>
    </android.support.v4.app.FragmentTabHost>
</RelativeLayout>
```

MainActivity.java

```
    package polimi.aap.yas.personalhealthrecord;
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
    import android.support.v4.app.FragmentTabHost;


    public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity {


        private FragmentTabHost mTabHost;

        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
           super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
           setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        mTabHost = (FragmentTabHost)findViewById(android.R.id.tabhost);
        mTabHost.setup(this, getSupportFragmentManager(), R.id.realtabcontent);
      mTabHost.addTab(mTabHost.newTabSpec("t1").setIndicator("Login"),Login.class,null);
        mTabHost.addTab(mTabHost.newTabSpec("t2").setIndicator("Register"),SignUp.class,null);


    }
}
```

build.gradle (module:app)

```
    apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.1"

    useLibrary 'org.apache.http.legacy'


    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "polimi.aap.yas.personalhealthrecord"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 23
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.1.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:23.1.1'
}
```

And finally this the logcat

> 12-09 14:53:14.184 3570-3570/? D/dalvikvm: Not late-enabling CheckJNI (already on)
>   12-09 14:53:14.314 3570-3570/? D/AndroidRuntime: Shutting down VM
>   12-09 14:53:14.314 3570-3570/? W/dalvikvm: threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0xb1777678)
>   12-09 14:53:14.334 3570-3570/? E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>                                                    java.lang.ClassCastException: polimi.aap.yas.personalhealthrecord.Login cannot be cast to android.support.v4.app.Fragment
>                                                        at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.instantiate(Fragment.java:423)
>                                                        at android.support.v4.app.FragmentTabHost.doTabChanged(FragmentTabHost.java:343)
>                                                        at android.support.v4.app.FragmentTabHost.onAttachedToWindow(FragmentTabHost.java:280)
>                                                        at android.view.View.dispatchAttachedToWindow(View.java:12125)
>                                                        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchAttachedToWindow(ViewGroup.java:2453)
>                                                        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchAttachedToWindow(ViewGroup.java:2460)
>                                                        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchAttachedToWindow(ViewGroup.java:2460)
>                                                        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchAttachedToWindow(ViewGroup.java:2460)
>                                                        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchAttachedToWindow(ViewGroup.java:2460)
>                                                        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1207)
>                                                        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1004)
>                                                        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:5481)
>                                                        at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:749)
>                                                        at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:562)
>                                                        at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:532)
>                                                        at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:735)
>                                                        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:730)
>                                                        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
>                                                        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
>                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5103)
>                                                        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
>                                                        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
>                                                        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:737)
>                                                        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
>                                                        at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
>   12-09 14:58:15.149 3570-3570/? I/Process: Sending signal. PID: 3570 SIG: 9

Do you see any problem? thank you in advance for your helps.
Let me add my objective by writing this code also. I need to have a tabhost to show two tabs (Login and Register). and fill the content of each tab by related layout(login.xml and signup.xml).

Login.java

```
    package polimi.aap.yas.personalhealthrecord;

import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;

public class Login extends AppCompatActivity {

    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    }
}
```

Comment: Could you post your Login class?

Comment: I've edited the question and append Login class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is that your `Login` class is an `AppCompatActivity`, and not a `Fragment`.

When you add a tab to the `TabHost`, you should pass a `.class` as you did. However, this `.class` should be from a defined `Fragment`, not `AppCompatActivity`.

So it should be

```
mTabHost.addTab(mTabHost.newTabSpec("t1").setIndicator("Login"),Login.class,null);
```

where

```
public class Login extends Fragment {
    /**/
}
```

Comment: Thanks! unfortunately Again I have problem! I changed both SignUp class and Login. but still ther is a fatal Exception .

Comment: @Yasi Have you imported the correct Fragment? i.e. 
    `import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;` and __NOT__ `import android.app.Fragment;`

Comment: Wow! thank you , it was the problem actually. @RafaelCardoso  :)